# how to join a subquery with conditions in Squeel

Tags: join, subquery, squeel

## Prologue

I've embraced Squeel – and enjoying every step! Thank you so much for sharing, Ernie Miller!

I'm developing with ruby 1.9.2 and Squeel 1.0.2 and Rails 3.2.5

(I'll confess to having restructured the question entirely - hoping to increase the readability and better my chances of getting an answer) <:)

## Use case

I'd like a (super)user to be able to assign authorizations and permissions like this

- a user_group should be able to have multiple authorizations
- an authorization should be able to have multiple permissions
- a permission should be able to control access to (manipulating) data

  - via the controller (the request path)
  - on instances of a Class
  - on any particular instance

The ACL system should be *lazy* – ie if no roles/authorizations are given, the users obviously  does not concern themselves with ACL at all.

## Migrations

I identified **role** and (a polymorphic) **roleable** entities from the use case an thus I have

a Role right out of the ordinary

```
create_table :roles do |t|
  t.references :ox
  t.string :name
  t.boolean :active, default: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

and a Roleable a bit more descriptive

```
create_table :roleables do |t|
  t.references :ox
  t.references :role
  t.references :roleable, polymorphic: true
  t.string :authorization
  t.string :controller
  t.boolean :active, default: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

## Classes

The system has a generic class - AbstractActionBase - which inherits from ActiveRecord:Base, and which all classes inherits from (allowing me to add systemwide attributes and methods in one place)

So - in part - my AbstractActionBase looks like

```
class AbstractActionBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class=true

  require 'tempfile'

  belongs_to :ox

  has_many :roleables, as: :roleable

  attr_accessible :ox_id

  validates_presence_of :ox_id

  #
  # all models inheriting from this will have versions
  has_paper_trail
  #
  #

  # 
  # Class method to providing for index SELECT's being married with roleables (permissions)
  # used from abstraction_actions_controller where build_collection calls this method 
  # the result 'should' be an ActiveRelation - used for the Kamanari 'result' call to readying pagination
  #
  def self.with_authorizations    

    # 
    # SELECT * FROM any_table at
    # left join (
    #     select r.roleable_id, r.roleable_type, group_concat( r.authorization )
    #   from roleables r
    #   where r.authorization is not null
    #   and r.roleable_id=at.id
    #   and r.roleable_type=at.base_class
    #   and r.role_id not in (1,2,3) <--- ID's are current_user.roles
    # ) rm on rm.roleable_id=at.id and rm.roleable_type=at.base_class
    #
    # which will provide for this:
    #
    # |.......| last column in table 'at' | roleable_id | roleable_type | authorizations |
    # |.......| some value                | 1           | 'UserGroup'   | 'insert,create'|
    # |.......| yet another value         | 92          | 'UserGroup'   | 'read'         |
    #
    #
    self.where{ active==true }
  end

  # compile a collection of records - regard search using Ransack
  def base.collection( params, resource_set )
    #
    # kaminari (and continous scrolling)
    #
    params[:page] ||= 1
    params[:per_page] ||= self.per_page
    params[:o] ||= self.resource_order_by
    distinct = params[:distinct].nil? ? false : params[:distinct].to_i.zero?
    resource_set = (resource_set.respond_to?( "result")) ? resource_set.result(:distinct => distinct) : resource_set
    (resource_set.respond_to?( "page")) ? resource_set.order(params[:o]).page( params[:page] ).per( params[:per_page] ) : resource_set.order(params[:o])
  end
end
```

Part of the Role class looks like this

```
class Role < AbstractActionBase

  has_many :roleables

  scope :active, where{ active.eq true }

  #
  # what does this role allow
  def permissions
    roleables.permissions.scoped
  end

  # 
  # to whom does this role allow
  def authorizations
    roleables.authorizations.scoped
  end

  # returns true if the roleables (permissions) authorizes the options
  # options are { controller: "", action: "", record: Instance, is_class: boolean }
  def authorizes?( options={} )
    coll = permissions
    coll = coll.on_action(options.delete(:action)) if options.keys.include? :action
    coll = coll.on_entity( options.delete(:record), options.delete(:is_class) || false ) if options.keys.include? :record
    coll = coll.on_controller(options.delete(:controller)) if options.keys.include? :controller
    (coll.count>0) === true
  end
end
```

The Roleable class looks like this

```
class Roleable  < AbstractActionBase
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :roleable, polymorphic: true

  # roleables authorizes users through user_groups
  # (in which case the authorization is "-")
  # providing them permissions on controllers, actions and instances
  scope :authorizations, where{ authorization == nil }
  scope :permissions, where{ authorization != nil }

  # using Squeel, find roleables on a particular controller or any controller
  def self.on_controller(ctrl)
    where{ (controller==ctrl) | (controller==nil) }
  end

  # using Squeel, find roleables on a particular authorization or allowed 'all'
  def self.on_action(action)
    where{ (authorization=~ "%#{action}%") | (authorization=="all") }
  end

  # using Squeel, find roleables on a particular instance/record or class
  def self.on_entity(entity, is_class=false)
    if is_class
      where{ ((roleable_type==entity.base_class.to_s ) & ( roleable_id==nil)) | ((roleable_type==nil) & (roleable_id==nil)) }
    else
      where{ ((roleable_type==entity.class.to_s ) & ( roleable_id==entity.id)) | ((roleable_type==nil) & (roleable_id==nil)) }
    end
  end
end
```

## Logic

### Creating

This allows me *authorizations* - assigning roles to someone/something - in which case the authorization string is nil, like

> The user_group **sales** is assigned the role **sales** 
>   with Roleable.create({ role: @sales, roleable: @user_group })

At the same time I can do *permissions* - describing the particulars of any role - like

> The role **sales** has *index*, *create*, *edit* and *delete* permissions 
>   on the OrderHead and OrderDetail tables with

- Roleable.create({ role: @sales, authorization: "index,create,edit,delete", roleable: @user_group, controller: "order_heads" })
- Roleable.create({ role: @sales, authorization: "index,create,edit,delete", roleable: @user_group, controller: "order_details" })

these 'particulars' can be ethereal like

> Roleable.create({ role: @sales, authorization: "index" })

somewhat real

> Roleable.create({ role: @sales, authorization: "index", roleable_type: 'OrderHead' })

or very expressed

> Roleable.create({ role: @sales, authorization: "index", roleable: OrderHead.first })

### Selecting

Most every controller inherits from AbstractActionsController where the index (and other actions) are defined. That controller it self inherits from InheritedResources:Base like this

```
class AbstractActionsController < InheritedResources::Base # < ApplicationController

  append_view_path ViewTemplate::Resolver.instance

  respond_to :html, :xml, :json, :js, :pdf

  belongs_to :ox, :optional => true

  before_filter :authorize!
  before_filter :authenticate!
  before_filter :warn_unless_confirmed!
  before_filter :fix_money_params, :only => [:create,:update]

  # GET /collection - printers
  def index

    # session[:params] = params
    #
    # preparing for Ransack
    unless params[:q].nil?
      params[:q]= { :"#{params[:q_fields]}" => params[:q] }
    end

    super do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js { render layout: false }
      format.pdf{ render :pdf => generate_pdf(false) and return }
      format.xml { render layout: false }
      format.json do
        # field lookup request?
        unless params[:lookup].nil?
          render layout: false, :json => collection.map(&:select_mapping)
        else
          render json: collection.map { |p| view_context.grow_mustache_for_index(p, collection, (parent? ? collection : resource_class.order(:id)), @selected ) }
        end
      end
    end
  end


  # the collection method on inherited_resources 
  # gets overloaded with Ransack search and Kaminari pagination (on the model)
  def collection
    # @collection ||= build_collection
    # TODO - test whether caching the collection is possible
    build_collection
  end

  def build_collection
    unless params[:belongs].nil?
      # debugger
      parent = params[:belongs].constantize.find(params[:belongs_id])
      @selected = parent.nil? ? [] : parent.send( rewrite_association(params[:assoc],parent) )
      @search_resource = core_entity(params[:assoc].constantize)
      @search_resource = @search_resource.search(params[:q]) unless params[:q].nil?
    else
      @search_resource = rewrite_end_of_association_chain(resource_class)
      @search_resource = core_entity(@search_resource)
      @search_resource = @search_resource.search(params[:q]) unless params[:q].nil?
    end
    # authorize rows
    @search_resource = @search_resource.with_authorizations                 # left joins roleables coalescing a "authorization" field from roles ID's not owned by current_user through his user_groups
    @resources ||= resource_class.collection( params, @search_resource )
  end

end
```

## Challenge

What a long story to presenting a short question <:)

How do I write the `with_authorizations` method to returning a ActiveRelation (and preferably using Squeel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said - preferably using Squeel :)

It turns out that (from the horses mouth so to speak) *joins are for associations* in Squeel-county ;)

So - what to do? Well, I did one last *tour de SO* with my SQL-to-ActiveRecord lasso swinging, and lo' and behold! Someone had asked a great question - and there was an even greater answer! Perfect.

In a few short almost fever blinded moments I hacked away using the technique described - and Heureka !!

Previously, I added a pastiebin to aid possible "answerees" - so I've added the result to the [pastiebin](http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=4ffd750774d38) - but in short it goes like this:

```
Model.select("something").joins("to your hearts contend")
```

Cheers,
Walther

Answer (score 1):

Walt,

You may be making this more complicated than necessary. If I'm reading this right, the primary purpose of the subquery is to get a concatenated list of the authorizations available in the results. If this is the case, you can simply eager_load authorizations and expose their names via a method on the Role model which does the concatenation for you. This has the secondary upside of being compatible with DBs other than MySQL.

Comment: Hi Ernie - thanks for getting back to me on this one! You might certainly be right about the _complicated_ part. I've tried to elaborate on my question. Does that still strike you as a "eager loading" case?

Perhaps I'm just not that _up to par_ on the eager-load – how would the eager_load look like in my situ?

Comment: Trying to beat you to it :) My with_authorizations method now is named x and has [this](http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=4ffd750774d38) definition - but when I try the last line: joins{rr}.where{id==rr.roleable_id}, or whatever I try, I draw blanks every single time :(

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to refer to the subquery in a joins call, as joins is reserved for associations. However, as mentioned before, if your primary reason for resorting to that subquery to do the join is to get that last column, the concatenated list of authorizations, I'd suggest breaking it down to the join of the roleables against any_table, then includes{roleables.authorizations}.

Comment: well - Ernie - sometimes you've gotta travel to enjoy _sweat home_ ;)